# Is TypeScript creating global variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, karma-mocha

I have created a file which has variables(so many of them) defined like

```
       > export const fruits: string[] = ["apple","orange","mango"];
```

I am using this way because I need to share these across my many test suites.

But now a days, I am noticing browser being crashed while running test cases due to memory being exhausted.
After making some heap profiling( this is my first attempt into this not sure though), I observed that arrays and objects are consuming so much memory.

Could it be a reason?

Comment: it just an array, how it possible it consume that much memory? the only memory consume a lot is where ur `loop` did not end properly

Comment: actually there are so many of these type of constants created this way for testing purpose.

Comment: Maybe an infinite loop? Your test imports an array, which is being tested, which imports an array, until infinity. The code above does not reproduce the error so to get a better answer you will have to include the test code too, in such a way that others can also generate the error.

Comment: @Kokodoko I am importing these types of variable in my different different test cases. My concern is that after finishing the test cases, will it be available for garbage collection.  To me it does not look so.

Comment: That really depends on how these arrays are used / tested. So to get a useful answer, you'll have to post your test code. Preferably in such a way that others will also get this memory leak error when they try your code.